# Looking for ways to use .htaccess rewrite rules without Allowing Override all in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

Some internet blogs say that

> Using .htaccess files and setting AllowOverride All is not recommended.

But I really want to use my rewrite rules.

My question is:
Is there a way to use `.htaccess rewrite rules` without Allowing Override all in `httpd.conf`? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. **AllowOverride All** is mandatary to allow override rewrite rules via a .htaccess file.